# Creating a process tree using fork() And then numbering them and showing it on array

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

I'm trying understand the fork() system call to work on Linux, and that's why i wrote the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int n = atoi(argv[1]);
  int i;
  pid_t pid;
  printf("Main:    PID: %d, PPID:%d\n", getpid(), getppid());
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if (pid = fork()) {
      pid = fork();
      if (pid > 0) {
        return (0);
      }
      if (i == n) {
        printf("We are in the level %d and as a child PID:%d,PPID:%d\n", n,
               getpid(), getppid());
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

What I did is: To create a process tree with depth n, where each process creates 2 children and then terminates. In the end I just printed out the child pids in the last level(so if n=3, there will be 8 children and i want to see the pids of these children). From my understanding, the code is working properly.(Please correct me if there's any mistake).

After this point, i wanted to change my code to do something like this:

```
        1
       / \
      /   \
     /     \
    /       \
   2         3
  / \       / \
 /   \     /   \
4     5   6     7
```

if n=2, for example. And i want to print out something like the following:

```
Last Level Children: 1 2 4
Last Level Children: 1 2 5
Last Level Children: 1 3 6
Last Level Children: 1 3 7
```

To do this i have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define SIZE 256

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int n = atoi(argv[1]);
  int i, k;
  int m = 1;
  int j = 0;
  int arr[SIZE];
  pid_t pid;
  arr[j] = m;
  m++;
  j++;
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    pid = getpid();
    if (pid = fork()) {
      arr[j] = m;
      m++;
      j++;
      pid = fork();
      if (pid > 0) {
        arr[j] = m;
        m++;
        j++;
        return (0);
      }
      if (i == n) {
        printf("Process tree: ");
        for (k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
          printf("%d ", arr[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But when i run the program, i seem to be getting the wrong results. What am i doing wrong here? Any help in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: `if(pid=fork()){
            pid=fork();` more fork is clearly always better.

Comment: I'm not sure if i get what you are saying, is it wrong that i'm doing this? I just did 2 forks to create 2 child process from the same parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that your child will continue the loop of their parent and create far more child that you think. I can only advice you to read twice the [manuel](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fork.html) of `fork()`. Manage process creation is not easy. You need to understand that your child will copy (~)all states of their parent. The same code will be execute for both, so you need to be careful about what code will be execute after your fork depend on the return value of `fork()`.

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113181/creating-a-process-tree-using-fork-and-then-numbering-them-and-showing-it-on-a#comment81176160_47113181) of EOF was for advice you to not have more that one `fork()` in a function. You will see that my exemple of implementation keep it simple by not having two `fork()` call, I isolate the call in one specific place.

Here a correct implementation of your first code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int create_two_child(int i, int n);

int main(void) { return create_two_child(0, 2); }

// tail recursive function: child will call this function to create two new
// child
static int create_two_child(int i, int n) {
  if (i < n) { // we look our level
    // debug output
    printf("DEBUG: We are in the level %d and as a child PID:%d, PPID:%d\n", i,
           getpid(), getppid());
    fflush(stdout); // we don't want child print parent output
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) { // we loop to create two child
      pid_t pid = fork();
      if (pid == -1) { // error
        perror("fork()");
        return 1;
      } else if (pid == 0) {               // child
        return create_two_child(i + 1, n); // we call ourself with i + 1 and
                                           // stop function here wich return we
                                           // don't want that child continue the
                                           // loop
      }
      // parent will continue the loop to the number of child wanted
    }
  } else {
    // if we are at max level we show our pid
    printf("We are in the level max %d and as a child PID:%d, PPID:%d\n", i,
           getpid(), getppid());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

second implementation where you want show the tree:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int create_two_child(size_t *backtrace, size_t id, size_t i, size_t n);

int main(void) {
  // we create array to stock id
  size_t backtrace[3];
  size_t n = sizeof backtrace / sizeof *backtrace;
  return create_two_child(backtrace, 1, 0, n);
}

// tail recursive function: child will call this function to create two new
// child
static int create_two_child(size_t *backtrace, size_t id, size_t i, size_t n) {
  if (i < n) {                       // we look our level
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 2; j++) { // we loop to create two child
      pid_t pid = fork();
      if (pid == -1) { // error
        perror("fork()");
        return 1;
      } else if (pid == 0) { // child
        backtrace[i] = id + 1;
        // id * 2 cause we create 2 child each time
        return create_two_child(backtrace, id * 2, i + 1,
                                n); // we call ourself with i + 1 and
                                    // stop function here wich return we
                                    // don't want that child continue the
                                    // loop
      }
      id++;
      // parent will continue the loop to the number of child wanted
    }
  } else {
    // if we are at max level we show our backtrace
    printf("Last Level Children: 1");
    for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      printf(", %zu", backtrace[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I just read the fork manual that you have inserted in the link and I wrote the code on my own again to understand. Much appreciated!..